# R: Extracting word between commas?

Tags: r, string, cpu-word

Say I have a string with various words separated by commas.

```
"Hello, 1000, "Oh shit, a comma", helloagain"
```

I want to take such a string, and given a value `n`, extract the word between the nth and (n+1)th comma.

So, for example, if `n = 1`, I want to extract `1000`.
If `n = 2`, I want to extract `"Oh shit, a comma"`. And so on.

How do I do this?

Note that the word between the commas can contain a comma in a quote ... and it can also be empty, e.g. the string could also be

`"Hello,, 1000"`

where for `n = 1`, we want the word `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you intend to keep the quoted string together (unsplit), here's an attempt:

```r
s <- "Hello, 1000, \"Oh shit, a_comma\", helloagain"
gre <- gregexpr("[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'", s)
unlist(lapply(regmatches(s, gre), function(z) {
  ifelse(grepl('^"', z), z,
         strsplit(gsub('"', '', z), "[ ,]+"))
}))
# [1] "Hello"                "1000"                 "\"Oh shit, a_comma\"" ""                    
# [5] "helloagain"
```

From here it's just simple indexing.

---

Another option that might be better, noting that somebody has likely already figured out how to properly tokenize optionally-quoted delimited text (which, when phrased that way, might spark the thought of `read.csv` or `read.table`). There's no real need to try to reinvent the wheel with regular expressions (https://xkcd.com/1171/).

```r
read.csv(text = s, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#      V1   V2                V3          V4
# 1 Hello 1000  Oh shit, a_comma  helloagain
```

If your vector of strings all have the same number of commas/fields, then you can use this as-is:

```r
read.csv(text = rep(s, 3), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#      V1   V2                V3          V4
# 1 Hello 1000  Oh shit, a_comma  helloagain
# 2 Hello 1000  Oh shit, a_comma  helloagain
# 3 Hello 1000  Oh shit, a_comma  helloagain
```

However, if they have different number of commas, you'll need to iterate over them a little more manually:

```r
out <- lapply(rep(s, 3), function(a) read.csv(text = a, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
out
# [[1]]
#      V1   V2                V3          V4
# 1 Hello 1000  Oh shit, a_comma  helloagain
# [[2]]
#      V1   V2                V3          V4
# 1 Hello 1000  Oh shit, a_comma  helloagain
# [[3]]
#      V1   V2                V3          V4
# 1 Hello 1000  Oh shit, a_comma  helloagain
```

and then you can grab the `n`th from each:

```r
sapply(out, `[[`, 2)
# [1] 1000 1000 1000
```

or a different index position from each:

```r
mapply(`[[`, out, c(1,3,2))
# [1] "Hello"             " Oh shit, a_comma" "1000"
```

Comment: Janus, does this answer your question?